# iTunes Connect: Find monthly retention of the app

Tags: app-store-connect

In iTunes Connect, we can analyse the apps daily retention rate i.e.,
"The percentage of users that first **installed** the app on a given day and used it again in the following days."

We can also define retention rate as "The percentage of users that first **used** the app on a given day and used it again in the following days."

I want to find out the **monthly retention rate** of our app i.e., "The **percentage of users that first installed/used** the app in a given month and used it again in following months**."

I couldn't find a way to do this in iTunes Connect. Any suggestions would be appreciated.